# How to decompress this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, compression, deobfuscation

I have a very confusing javascript code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var _8336;var _9264='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';var _1821=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;var _2581=2;var _2576=_9264.charAt(_9264.length-1);var _9238;var _1967=_9264.split(_1821);var _5737=[String.fromCharCode,isNaN,parseInt,String];_1967[1]=_5737[_2581+1](_5737[_2581](_1967[1])/21);var _4557=(_2581==7)?String:eval;_9238='';_11=_5737[_2581](_1967[0])/_5737[_2581](_1967[1]);for(_8336=3;_8336<_11;_8336++)_9238+=(_5737[_2581-2]((_5737[_2581](_1967[_8336])+_5737[_2581](_1967[2])+_5737[_2581](_1967[1]))/_5737[_2581](_1967[1])-_5737[_2581](_1967[2])+_5737[_2581](_1967[1])-1));var _1392='_5001';var _6523='_1392=_9238';function _7340(_8036){_4557(_7420);_7340(_7857);_7857(_6523);_7340(_1392);}var _7420='_7340=_4557';var _7857='_7857=_7340';_7340(_2576);
//]]>
    </script>
```

I want to convert these very confusing codes into something readable so that i can work on it and edit it.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Looks like it has been obfuscated deliberately to stop people changing it.

Comment: It's called "reverse engineering", and it sometimes takes time. Consider beautifying and debugging it.

Comment: Seems this is from [Templateify](http://www.templateify.com/).  Doubt they want you to be playing with it.

Comment: "*You are using a free version of our template, Buy full version to remove this sticker!'*" Code for a free template...tisk tisk..

Comment: Took me all of a minute to get the code. Beautify it and console log the variables. Walk the chain until the code appears. BUT the easiest solution is to pay for the template. ;)

Comment: Inlot of cases you can just replace eval with alert or console.log and see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

First, make the code more readable using http://jsbeautifier.org/:

```
var _8336;
var _9264 = /* [long hexadecimal string here] */;
var _1821 = /[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;
var _2581 = 2;
var _2576 = _9264.charAt(_9264.length - 1);
var _9238;
var _1967 = _9264.split(_1821);
var _5737 = [String.fromCharCode, isNaN, parseInt, String];
_1967[1] = _5737[_2581 + 1](_5737[_2581](_1967[1]) / 21);
var _4557 = (_2581 == 7) ? String : eval;
_9238 = '';
_11 = _5737[_2581](_1967[0]) / _5737[_2581](_1967[1]);
for (_8336 = 3; _8336 < _11; _8336++) _9238 += (_5737[_2581 - 2]((_5737[_2581](_1967[_8336]) + _5737[_2581](_1967[2]) + _5737[_2581](_1967[1])) / _5737[_2581](_1967[1]) - _5737[_2581](_1967[2]) + _5737[_2581](_1967[1]) - 1));
var _1392 = '_5001';
var _6523 = '_1392=_9238';

function _7340(_8036) {
    _4557(_7420);
    _7340(_7857);
    _7857(_6523);
    _7340(_1392);
}
var _7420 = '_7340=_4557';
var _7857 = '_7857=_7340';
_7340(_2576);
```

After trying a bit to understand how it works, you can determine that `_7340` is assigned to `eval`, `_1392` is assigned to the decrypted string, and you simply have to replace `_7340(_1392);` by `console.log(_1392);` in order to see the deobfuscated code in your browser's web console.